# Flink on YARN: how do I specify the number of Task Managers

Tags: apache-flink

In early versions of Flink, (e.g., [1.6](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/ops/deployment/yarn_setup.html)), I can specify the number of Task Managers for both session mode with `-n` and per-job mode with `-yn`, but the flags don't exist in later versions of Flink (e.g., [1.12](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/deployment/resource-providers/yarn.html)).

Wondering how should I set the number of Task Managers on YARN for newer versions of Flink? Or what are the related properties I can use to control the resources used by Flink?

Answer (score 2):

In newer versions of Flink, the resource manager dynamically launches task managers as needed to provide the number of slots requested by the job(s) that are submitted. Each task manager will take its configuration either from flink-conf.yaml, or from the parameters provided when the cluster is started via `yarn-session.sh`.

Comment: What are the relevant flags or properties? I see the number of slots for each task manager, but not the total slots.

Comment: You don't specify the total slots; that's not how it works. Task managers are created lazily, as needed (and released when no longer needed). Each time you submit a job, that job submission will require some number of slots (based on the parallelism of the job). At that point, enough task managers are created to provide the necessary slots.

Comment: See the sections on YARN in FLIP-6 https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/x/xRDiAw for more details about the new architecture that was introduced starting with Flink 1.5. Support for the legacy mode was later removed.

Comment: Thanks for your info! I now understand TaskManagers will be dynamically created, but still don't understand how. Say I use Flink to process a Kafka stream, is it based on the parallelism I specify? Parallelism=1 means single TaskManager, and N means N TaskManagers? I'll read the doc you linked, thanks again!

Comment: If parallelism=8, then 8 slots are needed. If each task manager provides 4 slots, then two task managers will be started.